# Ruby on Rails hosting: how do dynos and workers of Heroku compare to RAM of VPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, vps

Currently I am using Heroku and have never deployed to a VPS, which regarding [VPS prices in Europe](http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produkte_vserver/vq7) should be a lot of cheaper.

On Heroku my application requires 9 dynos and 2 workers. I am interested in how much server resources do I need for hosting my Ruby on Rails application on VPS, having the following server configuration:

- ubuntu
- nginx
- unicorn
- postgresql
- redis
- memcached

Also, can I put the latter three on the same VPS instance or is it a better practice to host databases and memcached separately?

Is there any way I could calculate server requirements myself?

For example, to how many dynos/workers I could compare a VPS with 7,2 GHz, 3GB RAM and 50GB storage? Would it be enough for my application?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, once you step above a few dynos and background processes the cost of a VPS vs the cost of Heroku will weigh the in VPS's favor.

However, the cost of the actual hosting is not your only cost.  For instance, a VPS will require some admin work from yourself, be it setup, software installation and configuration and keeping things up to date and running smoothly. Note this doesn't include learning how to do all of this stuff.

Once you factor these costs in (assuming you're working for paying clients and not doing this for fun), the answer rests firmly with Heroku - there is no other platform of the same maturity that lets you just fire and forget a deploy - the time savings alone are worth it.

http://neilmiddleton.com/why-heroku-is-a-game-changer/

Comment: Thank you, but I am certain, that I want learn all the server administration stuff myself no matter how much time it will take. The lower costs is not the only reason – the higher flexibility in the long term is as well.

Comment: And that's a good reason ;).  I stick with Heroku even though I know the server stuff purely because I value my time more than I do the cost of a VPS.  I've not been constrained that much by Heroku yet either.

Comment: @km: Just out of curiosity what flexibility are you looking for out of a VPS? I compared various options for a new project and settled on Heroku as it meets our current needs. Thanks

Comment: @DanRoberts There are several things the most prominent is the restriction of only one port. That means that you can't run unit tests for Play Framework. It will also severely limit you in remote debugging. You can't use web sockets or any other technique that requires ports.

Comment: Why are you looking to run unit tests on Heroku?  Do you often do remote debugging against your production environment?